# Find Bold Text Heading and put value in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to loop column A and find the bold "headings" and then take that value and put it Column F for each row.

Sample Data: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=58119513586509989991

You can see in the sample data, the actual data I am working with and the result I am trying to accomplish. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have so far. I just need to take the value of 'Heading' and paste it in Column F, row number 'ActiveCell.Row'

```
Sub Test2()
  Range("A1").Select
  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    If ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True Then
      Heading = ActiveCell.Value
    Else

    End If
    Debug.Print Heading
    Debug.Print ActiveCell.Row


    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop
 End Sub
```

Thanks,

sniper26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub AddHeadings()
    Dim heading As Range
    For Each cel In Range("A3:A20") '<~~ set it to the appropriate range
        If Trim(cel.Text) <> "" Then
            If cel.Font.Bold Then
                Set heading = cel
            Else
                If Not heading Is Nothing Then heading.Copy cel.Offset(, 5)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```